# Angular material stepper: Error: Cannot find control with name: 'formArray'

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I tried to follow up with the steps on how to setup angular material stepper here: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

I wanted a simple single form with multiple steps so I created this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper formArrayName="formArray" linear>
    <mat-step formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray.get([0])">
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step formGroupName="1" [stepControl]="formArray.get([1])">
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

I get on my console:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'formArray'
    at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1918)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.es5.js:1891)
    at FormGroupDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (forms.es5.js:4849)
    at FormArrayName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormArrayName.ngOnInit (forms.es5.js:5134)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10856)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12364)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12303)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13167)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13108)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MystepperComponent.htm
```

The full source code of my test is here: **[angular stepper test example on github](https://github.com/avidanyum/steppercheck)**

I really did my best to follow the documentation, but i don't understand what I need to do to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your `ngOnInit` has the formgroup definition like this,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

which doesn't have a `formArray` defined, so when you refer to `formArrayName="formArray"` in your template the app will expect a `formArray` control named 'formArray' within your parent formGroup declared as `formGroup` (in your case, from these 2 assignments:- `this.formGroup = ...` and `<form [formGroup]="formGroup">`). That explains the error you got to answer your question. But do you actually need a formArray there depends on what you are trying to accomplish and I don't think it matters as far as your question is concerned.

Also, you don't seem to be using the formControl defined as `firstCtrl` anywhere in your template. So essentially what you defined in your component as your reactive form (and its controls) doesn't match with what you have in your template except for just the parent formGroup name `formGroup`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, cool and complex :) so i'll try and remove completely formArray, formGroup all this stuff and see if it's working, will update.

Comment: removed all formGroup formArray formArrayName Ctrl and all looks working. thanks :) was just trying to follow the example...

Comment: @Jas, what was your final solution? I am struggling with the same.

Comment: @GenaroAlbertoCancinoHerrera Hi, I just cleaned my code it looks like I didn't need at all the formGroup formArray formArrayName so I just removed this code and it worked, did you try such a cleanup?

Comment: @Jas Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a single form with multiple steps you need to implement the `formGroup` and `formArray` in your component's typescript. To your problem it seems you have not implemented `formArray` in your component's typescript file. Modify your code as follows to make it work.

1. `stepper.component.ts` should look something like shown below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css']
})

export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({}),
        this._formBuilder.group({})
      ])
    });
  }
}
```

The two `this._formbuilder.group({})` within the array are for `formArray->'0'` and `formArray->'1'`.

2. Also update your `stepper.component.html` as shown below.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">  
  <mat-horizontal-stepper formArrayName="formArray" linear>    
    <mat-step formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([0])">
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step formGroupName="1" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([1])">
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

I have changed `formArray.get([0])` to `formArray?.get([0])` and `formArray.get([1])` to `formArray?.get([1])` as formArray is undefined.

3. Make sure you have all the required dependencies imported in `app.module.ts`.

You can find the working solution on the given link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuofwu

Comment: No need to change to: *formArray?.get([0])*, you can declare a variable as: *formArray: any;* and then on the *ngOnInit()* method, could initialize as: *this.formArray = this._formBuilder.array([ ...]);* and last, you can use it as: *this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({ formArray: this.formArray });*. ;)